# mysqli select id returning 0 (working on database)

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been looking in other questions but this seems something wrong with my own code and I wasn't able to identify the problem by myself.

I have the following query executing successfully and returning the id column I'm asking for:

```
SELECT city_id FROM location_city WHERE c_name = 'cityname'
```

However when I use my function to check if city exists I always get a 0 no matter what existing city I pass as parameter:

```
// check if city already exists
public function is_city($city) {

    $mysqli = $this->aet->getAetSql();

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT city_id FROM location_city WHERE c_name = ?')) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $city);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->num_rows === 1 ? $stmt->bind_result($city) : $city = FALSE;
    }

    return $city;
}
```

I've been doing some testing:

```
$city = 'Elche';
echo $functions->is_city($city);
if (FALSE !== $functions->is_city($city)) echo 'NOT FALSE'; else echo 'FALSE';

// 0
// NOT FALSE
```

I've also checked `$stmt->execute()` and it returns TRUE, no errors (`echo $stmt->error;`)

I also have another function that generates the city list and that's working ok. The only difference is that I'm not using `$stmt->store_result();` nor `$stmt->num_rows`. I tried commenting those two in `is_city()` but still not working.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your issue:

```
// check if city already exists
public function is_city($city) {

    $mysqli = $this->aet->getAetSql();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT city_id FROM location_city WHERE c_name = ?');

    if ( FALSE == $stmt ) {
       return FALSE;
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $city);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result( $city_id );
    if ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
       return $city_id;
    }

    return $city_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I see where the problem was.